# How can I resolve the Chrome warning: The deferred DOM Node could not be resolved to a valid node

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, google-chrome-devtools, web-inspector

I'm running a node.js project on a localhost server, and I've been doing this for months without seeing this, but recently, I've been getting this warning when I open the inspector:

```
The deferred DOM Node could not be resolved to a valid node.
```

I usually go into the inspector on an element to check out some attribute, eventListener, or other info, but this warning is popping up and it doesn't take me to the element. It's been pretty annoying, and I don't really know why it started showing up or how to get rid of it. My only clue is that I was changing some initialization settings for my express sessions around the same time this appeared, but I'm not sure that this is related.

Has anyone else run into this before? How do you get rid of the warning?
Thanks!

Comment: It has something to do with your code, but nobody can see it. It says it's about a "DOM node" so it's probably a client-side issue.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction - I've just never encountered this before. I wonder if I'm awaiting something that doesn't need it, or if I've deferred some script in my HTML that's holding up the rendering or something.

Comment: @shaedo That might be due to a chrome extension interfering. Make sure you test in an environment with no extensions

Comment: @Orkhan that was it. So weird, but running the test in incognito did the trick.

Comment: @shaedopotato Glad it helped. Posted as an answer

Comment: seeing this all the time, I am having to use FF more and more for dev, sucks. Prob smth to do with that lastpass

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That might be due to a chrome extension interfering. Make sure you test in an environment with no extensions like `incognito` mode.

Answer (score 12):

In my case, closing and reopening the browser window fixed it

Answer (score 4):

This can occur when debugging in Visual Studio. Usually, restarting the debugger solves the problem

Answer (score 1):

Open it in a incognito mode in chrome works!