# The deferred DOM Node could not be resolved to a valid node

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make a chrome extension to fill out forms.
So when the extension clicks a button to go to the next page, on the next page, the console shows this error: The deferred DOM Node could not be resolved to a valid node

I cannot inspect elements.

Please tell me what's likely the issue.

Comment: pls note https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72679147/how-can-i-resolve-the-chrome-warning-the-deferred-dom-node-could-not-be-resolve